# What is the longest PCIe card that can fit in a Dell R310

Tags: dell, pci-express

I have a full height 4" full length 13" PCIe Card that I need to fit into a R310 or other low end rack-mountable server.  Will this card fit? clearing the processor fan, memory, etc.

I've poured over the R310 Technical Reference but still have not found an answer.

http://i.dell.com/sites/content/shared-content/data-sheets/en/Documents/PowerEdge-R310-Tech-Guide-rev1.pdf

Comment: Link doesnt appear to work.

Comment: Don't forget to mark the correct answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You will not be able to fit a full-length 13" card in the R310. The usable depth of the slot is less than 7 inches.

The server has a riser with a PCIe slot on either side. The length of the card is limited by the processor cage and the memory bank.

[image]

Comment: Thanks you!, after reading a little more I confirmed the same thing on Page 10 of the Technical Guide, it supports full height half length.

After looking throught the models it looks like the R510 will support one full height full length PCIe card at x4 speed in slot 2.

Answer (score -1):

Servers use half-length cards for everything. The slot is much shorter so any full length card simply will not fit. most are pci-e. Larry

Comment: In addition to containing (questionable) generalsations, this answer adds nothing to the existing (excellent) answer, as far as I can see.